# False DescribeFeature Request URL in GeoExt QueryPanel

Tags: wfs, geoext, query, proxy, apache

I got the GeoExt QueryPanel working so far, it recognizes the layers available on my Geoserver but it is not able to get the attribute columns for the dataset. I configured an [osgeo proxy](http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/browser/trunk/openlayers/examples/proxy.cgi) on my Apache Server, I use the override-ext-ajax.js and have the `OpenLayers.ProxyHost = "/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi?url=";` class configured.

A DescribeFeatureType request is sent when selecting the layer I want to filter. The same happens when trying to choose the attribute column in the query panel, but there are none displayed.

The sent request URLs look like this:

```
http://localhost/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi?url=
http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fcgibin%2Fproxy.cgi%2Fwfs%3F
VERSION%3D1.1.0%26REQUEST%3DDescribeFeatureType%26TYPENAME%3Dcases%26query%3D
```

The strange part here is, that the request is sent via the proxy.cgi twice. The request URL should look like this, going passed geoserver´s WFS:

```
http://localhost/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi?url=
http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fgeoserver%2Fwfs%3F
VERSION%3D1.1.0%26REQUEST%3DDescribeFeatureType%26TYPENAME%3Dcases%26query%3D
```

Does anybody have a clue what´s going wrong here and why the request URL is wrong? The strange thing is that even if I remove the Open.Layers.ProxyHost class and the override-ext-ajax.js from my application, the request is sent that way. This leads to the conclusion, that the source of error can be found in the [QueryPanel.js](http://projects.opengeo.org/suite/browser/trunk/recipes/resources/extras/QueryPanel.js?rev=1708) file, yet I couldn´t spot it.

Can it, on the other hand be related to my server?

Other requests sent in the application (GET & POST) work fine. The (relevant) code looks like this, maybe you can spot the error.

```
OpenLayers.ProxyHost = "/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi?url=";

var owsUrl = "/geoserver/wfs";

var symbolizer = OpenLayers.Feature.Vector.style["default"];

symbolizer.graphicName = "square";

var store;

Ext.onReady(function() {

            store = new GeoExt.data.WFSCapabilitiesStore({
            url: Ext.urlAppend(owsUrl,
               "VERSION=1.0.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities"),
            protocolOptions: {version: "1.1.0"},
            autoLoad: true,
            listeners: {
                load: initApp
            }
            });
        });   

function initApp() {
        var vecLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Query", {
            eventListeners: {
                featuresadded: function() {
                    var extent = vecLayer.getDataExtent()
                    mapPanel.map.zoomToExtent(extent)
                }
            }
        });   



 var queryPanel = new gxp.QueryPanel({
            title: "Query",
            region: "center",
            width: 350,
            bodyStyle: "padding: 10px",
            autoScroll: true,
            layerStore: store,
            bbar: ["->", {
                text: "Query",
                handler: function() {
                    queryPanel.query();
                }
            }],
            listeners: {
                query: function(panel, store) {
                    var rule = new OpenLayers.Rule({
                        filter: panel.getFilter()
                    });
                    rule.symbolizer[queryPanel.symbolizerType] = symbolizer;
                    var style = new OpenLayers.Style("", {rules: [rule]});
                    wms.mergeNewParams({
                        sld_body: new OpenLayers.Format.SLD().write({
                            namedLayers: [{
                                name: panel.selectedLayer.get("name"),
                                userStyles: [style]
                            }]
                        })
                    });

                    store.bind(vecLayer, {
                        initDir: GeoExt.data.FeatureStore.STORE_TO_LAYER
                    });
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured the problem - think it was a setting that I made when having difficulties configuring a WFS. In GeoServer Globale settings, I set the Proxy Base URL to `http://localhost/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi?url=`

Answer (score 2):

At a quick glance I'd imagine the issue is around the lines below:

```
181         var protocol = record.get("layer").protocol;
182         this.attributeStore = new GeoExt.data.AttributeStore({
183             url: Ext.urlAppend(protocol.url, Ext.urlEncode({
184                 "VERSION": protocol.version,
185                 "REQUEST": "DescribeFeatureType",
186                 "TYPENAME": record.get("name")
187             })),
```

The tricky part will be debugging. To find out exactly what is happening, I'd make sure you set up the following:

1. Use the full source code, not a minified version, so you can debug it more easily
2. Use Firebug in FireFox
3. Put a [debugger](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Debugger;_keyword) line just before the code above. The code will stop at this point and you can check the url values, and where they are coming from.

Comment: It was indeed line 182 that created the wrong URL. When using firebug, I can temporarily change the URLs and make the queries work. Replacing line 182 with 
`url: Ext.urlAppend("http://localhost/geoserver/wfs", Ext.urlEncode({`, 
I can access the attribute names but queries are still sent via the proxy URL. Is there a way to change the URLs created by the QueryPanel.js permanently? If not, is there another way of fixing this problem?